# Custom LINQ-style implementation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I am looking to implement a very simple method to allow for use of the LINQ-style syntax. Example:

```
var res = ctx.Users.Where(x=>x.Name == "test" && x.Id > 1);
```

The `Where()` method is what I am trying to implement.

The overall idea is to have this `Where()` method perform a data source specific query to quickly fetch a subset of the data using a potentially-available index. Any subsequent method chained on will execute against the IEnumerable in-memory using LINQ-to-Objects.

I can get this to work using the following implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    //work with predicate body and return result of query
    return new List<T>();
}
```

The only issue I noticed is that performance is a little slow when building out the LINQ Expression object. This is significant as I am working with a very fast local (non-SQL) store. Is there any way to just grab the raw input as a string (or some other format) so that I can use custom parsing logic? I am aware that I could just make this a string parameter, but I do really like the type checking I get with the LINQ lambda syntax.

Comment: Parsing a string shouldn't be faster then dealing with an expression. Maybe it's worthy to post your code

Comment: This is certainly an X/Y problem...you think the issue is X but it's most likely Y.  Why don't you post what you NEED, not what you think you WANT.

Answer (score 0):

By way of answering the question, I think an extension method will give you want you want. The method would look something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> MyWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        //process each item individually
        List<T> returnValue = new List<T>();
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            string stringToParse = t.ToString();

            //do things
            string parsedString = stringToParse.ToUpper();

            //create your new object and add to the list that will be returned
            returnValue.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parsedString));
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

This likely won't net you a performance improvement. Also, the method does all the calculation up front instead of feeding results one-by-one (using the `yield` feature); however, that's an easy modification:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> MyWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        //process each item individually
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            string stringToParse = t.ToString();

            //do things
            string parsedString = stringToParse.ToUpper();

            //return your transformed object
            yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parsedString);                
        }
    }
```

Quick note: because you want your method signature to be the same as `IEnumerable.Where`, you'll want to choose a different method name.